# Error opening CA private key (OpenSSL on windows)

Tags: openssl, certificate

When i want create the certificate

```
openssl ca -days 3650 -in D:\FEU\client.cert.req -out D:\FEU\clientcert.pem -config openssl.cfg
```

I get the following error:

```
Error opening CA private key ./demoCA/private/cakey.pem
```

in that folder is that file, i can create the key pair and the client key pair without problems.

Comment: What is inside openssl.cfg?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also, you should add more details because any number of things could be wrong. For example, add the output of `ls` for the directory in question.